# Memory leaks when using shared pointers in a vector

Tags: c++, vector, memory-leaks, shared-ptr

I've been facing a problem with memory leaks when adding a shared pointer to a vector, the vector is defined as follows:

```
vector<shared_ptr<Recipe>> favorites;
```

(Recipe is a simple class with 2 simple fields)

and the following function is used to add a recipe to the user's favorites:

```
void User::postRecipe(string recipeName) {
    if (!(*this).isConnected())
        throw UserNotConnectedException();
    if (!(*this).isInGroup())
        throw NotInGroupException();
    shared_ptr<User> owner = server->seekUser((*this).getId());
    shared_ptr<Recipe> recipe(new Recipe(recipeName, owner));
    server->postRecipe((*this).groupName, recipe);
    if (!checkIfRecipeInFavs(favorites, recipeName)) {
        favorites.push_back(recipe);
}
```

Although the program compiles and the output of the program is as desired, the last line of this functions seems to cause a memory leak and the error disappears if it was removed.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Recipe.h:

```
class Recipe
{
    string name;
    shared_ptr<User> owner;
public:
    Recipe(string name, shared_ptr<User> owner):name(name),owner(owner){};
    ~Recipe(){};
    string getName();
    shared_ptr<User> getOwner();
};
```

Recipe.cpp:

```
string Recipe::getName(){
    return name;
}
shared_ptr<User> Recipe::getOwner(){
    return owner;
}
```

Comment: _'the last line of this functions seems to cause a memory leak ...'_ How exactly are you detecting this?

Comment: Tip: you can use `this->member` instead of `(*this).member`. That would make the code more readable.

Comment: using Valgrind, when this line is removed Valgrind detects no errors

Comment: @NizarElias Does the class `Recipe` have a copy-constructor, an assignment operator or a destructor? If yes, try removing them (the bug is probably there). Also, post their code (edit your question and add the code) if that doesn't help.

Comment: @NizarElias Valgrind is sometimes wrong about possible leaks, you should put the actual messages you get, also to your question ([please edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/24374456/edit)), that would help analyzing what the real problem is.

Comment: If your `favorites` vector is never destroyed (i.e. it's a global variable) then the contents won't be destroyed either.

Comment: @NizarElias and post a link to the valgrind report (you can use [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/))

Comment: @anatolyg the Recipe class is very simple so we didn't bother making any of these, will edit the question and add the code :)

Comment: @Scis No, I think it's better to put the (essential parts of) valgrind report to the question itself.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ **Exactly** :) *The essential parts of*. It's just that it tends to be very messy when the whole valgrind report is pasted into the question and makes the the question gigantic.

Comment: What makes you think the `User` object that is holding all these shared pointers in a `favorites` member isn't itself the root of the leak? Your posted code has a circular ownership. Users own recipes, and each recipe has said-same user in *it's* ownership list.

Answer (score 8):

When you store the owner in the Recipe using another shared pointer, you create a cyclic reference, meaning, the Recipe will only be deleted when the User is deleted, but the User will only be deleted when all Recipes are deleted. You should use [`weak_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/weak_ptr) in Recipe to break the cycle.

This is because `shared_ptr` uses simple reference counting to determine when it should delete its pointee: Whenever you copy a `shared_ptr`, its reference count (kept on the heap, alongside with the pointee object) is incrementented, and whenever a copy gets destroyed, the count is decremented. The pointer which sees the count reach zero in its destructor will delete the object. When two `shared_ptr`s reference each other, the count will never fall below two.

Comment: Thank you for your informative answer, i do now understand the problem, any suggestions how to fix it? would a simple replace all where i replace all the `shared_ptr` in my code to `weak_ptr` solve this? thanks once more!

Comment: @NizarElias You should consider ownership when dealing with smart pointers. Presumably, `User` owns a `Recipe` and should therefore hold a `shared_ptr`. Since the `Recipe` does not _own_ the object pointed to by `owner`, it should be a `weak_ptr`.